# Error querying by tag values in Azure IoT registry

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a device with the following tag value:

```
{
  "deviceId": "test",
  "tags": {
    "group": {
      "name": "beta1"
    }
}
```

When I query with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE tags.group.name = 'beta1'
```

I get the following error:

```
There was an error querying devices: BadRequest:{ "Message": "ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;BadRequest", "ExceptionMessage": "Tracking ID:c6985322e3014555bc7bcb4892292394-G:9-TimeStamp:10/17/2018 12:22:07" }.
```

However, if I query for a non-existent tag, no error is thrown:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE tags.foo.bar = 'beta1'
```

How do I query for my tag value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we can not use a query for 'group' property in the device twin. Workaround is to rename it, for instance _group.

I am guessing this is a bug.

**Update:**
The issue has been fixed:

```
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE tags.[[group]].name = 'beta1'
```

more details: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17106#issuecomment-433177700

Comment: I guess it was just luck that I happened to pick that name! Thanks.